# Renaming all files in a folder_adding a part to it

Tags: rename, file-rename

I have several MAGs named as follows in a folder.

bin.10.fa  bin.14.fa  bin.17.fa  bin.1.fa   bin.24.fa  bin.27.fa  bin.2.fa   bin.32.fa  bin.35.fa  bin.3.fa   bin.44.fa  bin.48.fa  bin.50.fa  bin.54.fa  bin.7.fa

I would like to rename it to b3_bin,x.fa, where x is the number from original file.

How can i do this on terminal ?

i tried rename

```
rename -v 's/bin.x.fa/b3_bin.x.fa /zfs/camplab/Jojy/darpa_working/drep_mags_all/b3_renamed/b3.bin.x.fa/*.x.fa
```

it failed.
it showed running, but no output